# If statement works the first time, but not the second time

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, dos

I'm having this problem with the **** IF NOT processed == %true% ****.
The problem is that it's staying in the loop when it shouldnt.
I tried the otherway around IF processed == %false% it goes in the loop BUT doesnt go back in the 2nd time. sometimes, it goes in up to 3 times.

my "echo !processed! process" is always giving me the right number but the IF statement is just not processing the second time around

%TRUE% AND %FALSE% are global variable 1 and 0

```
   setlocal  
    :loopapp  
    **if not '!processed!'=='%TRUE%'** (  
        set /a count+=1
        "%ProgramFiles%\abc\abc.exe" !file! !post!  
        call :ERRORCODES !file! !post! !ERRORLEVEL! !count!  
        goto :loopapp  
    )
    endlocal

:ERRORCODES
setlocal
if %errornum% LEQ 99 (  
    set no_license=%FALSE%  
    if '!post!'== 'A' set no_license=%TRUE%  

    if '!no_license!'=='%TRUE%' (
            echo    Searching ... '!count!' ... Please Wait ...
            if !count! EQU 5 (
                set execute=%TRUE%
                set succes=%FALSE%
                echo %~n1 - Fatal - process %TIME% >> %tempfolder%\errorlog.txt
                goto :END
            )  
            set execute=%FALSE%  
            set succes=%FALSE%  
            goto :out_errorcodes  
    )
    set execute=%TRUE%
    set succes=%FALSE%
    echo %~n1 - Fatal - process %TIME% >> %tempfolder%\errorlog.txt  
    goto :out_errorcodes 
)  

... other errors  

:out_errorcodes  
endlocal & set processed=%execute% & set fait=%succes%  
goto :EOF
```

Comment: i've finally used the :ERRORCODES with no setlocal, no longer using it as a subprogram.  It seems like a subprogram calling another subprogram doesnt work well at all... thx anyway!

Answer (score 5):

**1)** I don't see where you define what `TRUE` and `FALSE` are - they are certainly not standard batch values.

If you are trying to set up variables that function as boolean flags, then I recommend the following.

To set the flag to false, use `SET "FLAG="`. This "undefines" the flag.

To set the flag to true, use `SET "FLAG=1`. Note that the value 1 has no significance. You could use any value as long as it is not empty.

To test if the flag is true use `IF DEFINED FLAG ECHO FLAG IS TRUE`

To test if the flag is false use `IF NOT DEFINED FLAG ECHO FLAG IS FALSE`

The reason I like this technique is that DEFINED is evaluated at execution time, not parse time. So it is safe to use this test within any block of code such as within a FOR loop, and you don't have to worry about delayed expansion.

**2)** I haven't bothered to try to trace your logic. It would be good if you can come up with a minimal amount of code that demonstrates the problem.

**3)** If you have used ECHO OFF elsewhere, try setting ECHO ON just prior to the IF so that you can see what the batch script is attempting to do.

*(I thought perhaps you were missing SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion, but now I see your report that `echo !processed! process` works.)*

Comment: the problem is not with the true or false... its the IF statement not working.  tried to put 0 instead and still doesnt work. tried if 0==0 too!  also, how can a IF statement work the first time and NOT the second time...

Answer (score 1):

The reason your subprogram does not seem to work is because you made a little error in it.

```
endlocal & set processed=%execute% & set fait=%succes%
```

You have a space between %execute% and &.
That space will also be in the %processed% variable's value.
So in your if statement this will be true

```
'!processed!'=='%TRUE% '
```

To avoid having that space in the %processed% variable use this

```
endlocal & set processed=%execute%& set fait=%succes%
```

This is also documented on [SS64](http://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html)